# Wiring Help Lutron Diva Dimmer and Claro 3-Way with Claro First in Line

Tags: dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I am having trouble figuring this out.  Attached is a diagram, best I could do given the tools I have. Please remember I am not an electrician so explain like I am 5 please.  In a nutshell, the 14/2 hot from the breaker comes into the electrical box where the Claro 3-way switch is located.  The Claro has 4 screws -- copper, ground and 2 silvers.  Out of that box goes the 14/2 to the light fixtures and the 14/3 to the other side of the room where the Diva Dimmer is located.  The Diva has 4 wires already attached - black, red, red/white and green.  Now ground goes to ground so that part I have figured out, but I am unsure of the correct setup here.  All the diagrams I can find have the Lutron dimmer first or are just for two conventional 3-way switches and that is confusing me for this setup.  Thanks for any help that can be given or if someone has a diagram for this. -Alan

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many 3-way diagrams you will have the feed come in to one switch, and the outgoing wire to the light at the other switch.  You have the feed and the output in one box, so you need an extra hot wire to go between the two boxes.  Because you have a green wire, I think you might have conduit.  If that is the case, the best option is to run another colored wire between the two switches to act as the common wire to the Diva.

If you cannot run an extra wire, you can use the white wire as the common return, and you note that by marking the white wire with black tape (because it will be a hot wire in this scenario).

In either case, the wire connections should be as follows.  On the Claro, connect the black wire that is the power into the box to the different-colored screw on the outlet.  The red and black "travelers" that go from box to box will connect to the other two screws.  The whites from the feed and the output to the light should be connected together.  The common return (new wire or black taped white wire) will get connected to the black wire that goes to the light.

In the Diva box, the taped white wire will go to the different-colored screw, and the red and black get connected to the other two screws.  And of course, all grounds get tied together and attached to the two switches.

Comment: Thanks.  One clarification.  On the Diva, the wires are already there.  Black, Red, Red/White and Green. Green is ground so I have that covered.  So given your advice above, it sounds like the Red and Black travelers will go to the Diva's Red and Red/White wires.  And my taped White (white with black) will go to the Black (which I assume is hot).  Does this sound correct?  Also, can't run another wire.

Comment: I also added a picture that comes from the Lutron website where it is to walk me through the setup.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, looking at that picture, the black taped white will go to the black pigtail, and the red and black travelers will attach to the red and red/white pigtails.  Just to reword what you said...

Comment: Thanks!  Gonna go give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen just the right set of products for this to work. The Claro appears to be a plain 3-way switch with a fancy handle.  The Lutron was deliberately chosen to be neutral-less.

### Mark the wires

Normally I say mark the pair of travelers yellow, and switched-hot red.  However, that would mean marking every wire in your setup, so instead let's just say **2 reds are travelers**, and black is switched-hot.

In the /3 cable, mark the white wire black. **This is mandatory**. This is not a "Harper"ism, it's NEC.  You have to do it.

Also in the /3 cable, mark the black wire red - that's a "Harper"ism.  *"Wait, why didn't we just ..." because NEC*.

On the Lutron dimmer, mark the red-white wire just red.

### Hook it up

At the left switch (Claro 3-way), hook the common to the lamp hot (black).  Hook the 2 travelers to the 2 red wires.  (remember we remarked /3 black).

Also in that box, connect supply hot (black) to the /3 black wire (the white which we remarked). We're done there.

The right box has black-red-red, as does the Lutron.  (taking remarkings into account, of course). Match em up 1:1 just like that!  Done.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was to follow these instructions https://webapiaw1proddat01st01.blob.core.windows.net/assets/documents/0301710_Caseta_Advanced_Instructions.pdf

But even then it didn't work. What DID work was to switch the claro from the location it was intended to where the rocker I didn't want replaced was.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).