# How do I wire a smart switch in electrical box that contains 4 neutral wires?

Tags: wiring, neutral, smart-switch

I'm trying to install a Lutron Claro smart switch in my bathroom which shares an electrical box with a Lutron diva smart dimmer. The dimmer doesn't require a neutral and works fine, but I can't figure out how to connect the neutrals to make the Claro work.
There are 4 neutral wires in the box that were all connected together, 3 of which come from above and 1 coming from below. Anybody know which neutrals to connect to the Claro and which to cap off separately?
Connecting all 4 neutrals from the wall with the neutral from the Claro didn't work.

[image: smart switch connected to a different box just so you can see the switch (it has green, black, red, white, and a blue that doesn't get used according to the instructions since my application is single pole]
[image: full box and wires]

[image: close up of box]  [image: close up of box]

Comment: here is the storage part `Connecting all 4 neutrals from the wall with the neutral from the claro didn't work.
`

Comment: maybe this answer would help :https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/186946/157970

Comment: None of the white wires are "spare" and need to be capped off. All of them have a purpose in that box, and they all need to remain connected together as they were. If you leave them all connected together as they were and add the dimmer's neutral to the bundle, but the dimmer doesn't work, then the problem is not with the neutrals.

Comment: @brhans Hmm maybe I'll try connecting the switch to a simpler electrical box to see if the switch itself works. Something is definitely not working. Connecting all neutrals together with the switch results in the dimmer working (which doesn't require a neutral), but the switch doesn't work at all. In this scenario, there's no semblance of life in the switch.

Comment: If I connect a couple of the neutrals to the switch and a couple others together in a separate wago connector, I can get the fan controlled by the switch to power on and the indicator light on the switch glows (but the switch doesn't work to power on or off the fan), so that tells me that the switch isn't completely dead but it's possible that it's malfunctioning since it's not working when connected to all the neutrals.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add a couple of pics (use the "sun & mountains button") of the box, switch & wiring.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for trying to help. I attached pics. The first is the switch in a different box, just so you can see the wires coming out of the switch I'm trying to use (black, red, white, green, and a blue that doesn't get used since this is single pole). The other 3 pics show the box and wiring. Each of the 4 cables going into the box have a black, white, and ground.

Answer (score 2):

All of the neutrals, white wires, need to be connected together. there's probably only one real neutral from the main panel so all need to b connected together so they will all be neutrals. Maybe you failed to connect them all together... try it again.

Comment: I took a closer look at the wiring. All 4 romex cables (I think that's what they're called?) each have: 1 black, 1 white, and ground. Two of the black wires are pigtailed to red wires (those black wires come from 1 cable that comes from the top of the electrical box and 1 from the bottom of the box).

Comment: I tried to connect all 5 neutrals together using a red wire nut and using a 5 port wago connector. Neither worked, so I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Are you sure the other connections are right, the line and load wires?

Comment: I believe so. I connected them exactly the same as the last (non-smart) switch which had been working without a problem. Black on top, red below that.

Comment: Typically the smart switch also requires a neutral connection, to power it's own circuitry. You have accounted for that too, right?

Comment: You don't wire them the same as  the last switch.... you wire them as the specific instructions state .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what craziness is going on in your 1st pic with the neutrals all spread out between various things ... so I'm going to ignore that pic and pretend I didn't see it.
Judging by what I see in the 2nd pic, the loose red wire is your incoming hot wire (since it's bundled together with a few other wires) and according to the [Lutron Claro installation instructions](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/f4/f43393cd-ca0e-41a4-9de0-e62be9e9fa73.pdf), that needs to go to the *black* wire on the switch.
That leaves the loose black wire in the box as your *load* wire which runs out to the light or fan or whatever it powers, and you connect your switch's *red* wire to that one.
The switch's white goes over to join in with all the other white neutrals, and don't forget to tie the green ground wire from this switch (as well as the one from the dimmer) in with all the bare ground wires in the box.

So:

- red to black
- black to red
- white to bundle of white neutrals
- green to ground
- cap and ignore the blue

Comment: Thank you so much! You're absolutely correct and that worked perfectly. (I neglected to mention that the first pic contains a bunch of wires that are covered in white paint haha)